# Trouble with while loop

Tags: java

Still brand new to programming all of a week now. Been writing small programs to help get the basics stuck in my head. When I run this code, it runs correctly if I enter the first question correct, but if I answer it wrong & then it loops back around and I answer it correct again, it keeps looping without continuing to the rest of the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Parker {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How old are you: ");
        int age = scan.nextInt();
        if (age > 6) {
            System.out.println("You are to old for the program");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the program, enjoy!");
                    System.out.println("What is 5 + 3? ");
                    int num1 = scan.nextInt();
                    if (num1 == 8) {
                        System.out.println("Correct!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Wrong! I'm telling your DADDY!");
                    }
                    while (num1 != 8) {
                        System.out.println("What is 5 + 3? ");
                        int num9 = scan.nextInt();
                        if (num9 == 8) {
                            System.out.println("Correct!");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Wrong! I'm telling your DADDY!");
                    }
                    }
                    System.out.println("What is 3 + 11? ");
                    int num2 = scan.nextInt();
                    if (num2 == 14) {
                        System.out.println("Correct!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Wrong! I'm telling your DADDY!");
                    }
                    System.out.println("What is 7 + 6? ");
                    int num3 = scan.nextInt();
                    if (num3 == 13) {
                        System.out.println("Correct!");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Wrong! I'm telling your DADDY!");
                    }
                    System.out.println("What is 11 - 5? ");
                    int num4 = scan.nextInt();
                    if (num4 == 6) {
                        System.out.println("Correct!");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Wrong! I'm telling your DADDY!");
                    }
                    System.out.println("What is 4 + 9? ");
                    int num5 = scan.nextInt();
                    if (num5 == 13) {
                        System.out.println("Correct!");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Wrong! I'm telling your DADDY!");
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (num1 != 8)`; you don’t change the value of `num1` in the loop.

Comment: after num1 == 8, need a break; statement to come out of loop..please see my code below.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (num1 != 8) {
    System.out.println("What is 5 + 3? ");

    int num9 = scan.nextInt();

    if (num9 == 8) {
        System.out.println("Correct!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong! I'm telling your DADDY!");
    }
}
```

The above condition in your code depends on `num1`, but you never change the value of `num1` within that loop. For that reason, that loop will never terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Change this,

```
while (num1 != 8) {
System.out.println("What is 5 + 3? ");
int num9 = scan.nextInt();
    if (num9 == 8) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
    } else {
    System.out.println("Wrong! I'm telling your DADDY!");
}
```

to this,

```
while (num1 != 8) {
System.out.println("What is 5 + 3? ");
int num9 = scan.nextInt();
    if (num9 == 8) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
    break;
    } else {
    System.out.println("Wrong! I'm telling your DADDY!");
}
```

By the way, you should only use one variable for getting input from scanner, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score -2):

Here you have!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Parker {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        int numl = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How old are you: ");
        int age = scan.nextInt();
        if (age > 6) {
            System.out.println("You are to old for the program");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the program, enjoy!");
            System.out.println("What is 5 + 3? ");

            numl = scan.nextInt();
            while(numl != 8) {
                System.out.println("Wrong! I'm telling your DADDY!");                   
                System.out.println("What is 5 + 3? ");
                numl = scan.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println("Correct!");   

            System.out.println("What is 3 + 11? ");

            numl = scan.nextInt();
            while(numl != 14) {
                System.out.println("Wrong! I'm telling your DADDY!");                   
                System.out.println("What is 3 + 11? ");
                numl = scan.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println("Correct!");      

            System.out.println("What is 7 + 6? ");

            numl = scan.nextInt();
            while(numl != 13) {
                System.out.println("Wrong! I'm telling your DADDY!");                   
                System.out.println("What is 7 + 6? ");
                numl = scan.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println("Correct!");    

            System.out.println("What is 11 - 5? ");

            numl = scan.nextInt();
            while(numl != 6) {
                System.out.println("Wrong! I'm telling your DADDY!");                   
                System.out.println("What is 11 - 5? ");
                numl = scan.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println("Correct!");  

            System.out.println("What is 4 + 9? ");

            numl = scan.nextInt();
            while(numl != 13) {
                System.out.println("Wrong! I'm telling your DADDY!");                   
                System.out.println("What is 4 + 9? ");
                numl = scan.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println("Correct!");  
        }
    }
}
```